# 32bit ODBC Driver not Installing correctly on Windows 7 64 bit machine

Tags: advantage-database-server

I am having a problem installing the 32 bit Advantage ODBC driver (v9.10) on a Windows 7 64 bit computer.  When I run the install routine, I am logged on under the local Administrator account and the install completes without any errors.  When I open the 32 bit ODBC manager and try to add a new System (or User) DSN, I get the following error message:  "The Setup routines for the Advantage Streamline SQL ODBC ODBC driver could not be found.  Please reinsall the driver".  Rerunning the install routine (with the repair option) and/or removing/reinstalling the driver does not resolve the problem.  I've also noticed that when I'm creating the DSN and I go to select the driver, the Advantage driver is listed but the Version, Company, File and Date fields are all blank.

Has anyone else see this and have a fix for it?

Thank you!

Comment: Better on serverfault.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution to this.  When I was intalling the driver, I had selected the option to install it for Everyone.  I uninstalled/reinstalled it only this time selecting the option to install it just for me.  For whatever reason, this fixed the problem and the driver installed/registered correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the connection by using the 32 bit ODBC Data Source Administrator. Instead of going through administrative tools use \Windows\SysWow64\odbcad32.exe.

Answer (score 1):

You will definitly want to use the 32-bit ODBC Data Source Administrator as the other two have said.
However, I do have one other suggestion you may try.  I have seen this work when the driver does not get registered properly for some reason so it may help in this case.

Try copying the adsset.dll from  C:\Program Files (x86)\Advantage \ODBC to c:\windows\SysWow64 and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I havent dealt with Advantage, but I do know other drivers which are 32bits and installed on 64 bit machines.
Try installing the driver in your 32bit folder i.e the C:/Windows/SysWOW64 folder. see if that helps